# stored procedure with wildcard parameters

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I've a table

```
create table user (userId varchar(8) not null, userName varchar(8) not null)
   insert into user
     select 'NAME1','name1'
     union all
     select 'NAME2', 'name2'
     union all
     select 'NAME3','name3'
```

I've used stored procedure for wild card parameters as:

```
create procedure wildcard_name
@userName nchar(8)=  '%'
as
select * from user
where userName like @userName;

exec wildcard_name 'n%';
```

the exec statement is not giving any result,why?

Comment: Also your insert statement doesn't work, did you forget quotes around those strings, or was this adapted from an `insert/select`? Collation might play a role too - if the collation is case sensitive, `'Nancy' LIKE 'n%'` will return false.

Comment: @Mitch that's a good point, but at worst in this specific case it would introduce implicit conversions, not change the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try running it again? I suspect the exec call is part of the body of your procedure now. How about:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.wildcard_name
  @userName NVARCHAR(8) = '%'
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT userId, userName
    FROM dbo.user
    WHERE userName LIKE @userName;
END
GO -- <-- this is important! It tells SSMS that your procedure has ended!

EXEC dbo.wildcard_name N'n%';
```

Bunch of other suggestions I would be remiss to not mention:

- You should always specify the schema prefix when creating and calling objects. So `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.wildcard_name`, `EXEC dbo.wildcard_name`, etc.
- Hopefully your production code does not use `SELECT *`.
- Highly recommend using nvarchar instead of nchar for your parameter.
- Wrap your procedure body with `BEGIN` / `END` and don't be afraid to use indenting to make it much more readable.
- You'll usually want to use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to prevent `n row(s) affected` messages from interfering with your results.
- `NVARCHAR` parameters should have an N prefix (though I'm confused why you're alternating between `varchar` and `nchar` in the first place - this is two shifts where I'd expect zero).
- Depending on the collation (and whether you want the search to be case sensitive), you may need to change your where clause using the `COLLATE` clause.

**EDIT** this seems to work just fine for me, so please explain what you are doing differently (and does "did not work" still mean empty result, or something else?):

[image]

Comment: thanks Aaron Bertrand for ur valuable suggestions. But my above post was just to save space. As from ur reply I did EXEC dbo.wildcard_name N'n%'; but it did not work.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you've used (get this using `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.wildcard_name'));`. If you're still using the original `create procedure` code without the `GO`, I think you're still not actually calling the stored procedure, because the `EXEC` has become part of the stored procedure body. And please don't say vague/generic things like "it did not work." This is like expecting a specific prescription from the doctor when all you've told him/her is that you don't feel so good. Or calling the mechanic and telling him your car is "broken."