# Gridview Search

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, gridview

I have created a stored procedure which searches the gridview based on input and it is as follows:

```
Create procedure spSearch
( 
@Emp_id nvarchar(50) = null,
@Emp_name nvarchar(50) = null,
@Emp_exp nvarchar(50) = null,
@Emp_address nvarchar(50) = null
) 
AS 
BEGIN

If @Emp_id is not null and Len(@Emp_id )=0 Set @Emp_id = null
If @Emp_name is not null and Len(@Emp_name )=0 Set @Emp_name = null
If @Emp_exp is not null and Len(@Emp_exp )=0 Set @Emp_exp = null
If @Emp_address is not null and Len(@Emp_address )=0 Set @Emp_address = null

Select *
From tbl_employee
Where 
(@Emp_id is null or Emp_id Like @Emp_id )
and ( @Emp_name is null or Emp_name Like @Emp_name )
and ( @Emp_exp is null or Emp_exp Like @Emp_exp )
and ( @Emp_address is null or Emp_address Like @Emp_address )
END
```

However, this return's the search items only when the input exactly matches the already stored data.

```
Eg : In tbl_employee I have 
Emp ID = 1
Emp_name = peter
Emp_exp = 2 years
Emp_address = xyz
```

Only when I enter Emp_name as "peter" the search result is getting populated in gridview.
I need to modify the stored procedure so that even if I enter "pe" in the textbox, all the data which contains "pe" should be populated.

This is the c# code :

```
private DataTable Search()
           {

               DataTable SearchResultsTable = new DataTable();

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


           try
              {

              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearch", conn);
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_id", txtEmpID.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_name" , txtEmpName.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_exp " , txtEmpExp.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_address " , txtEmpAddress.Text);
              SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              adapter.Fill(SearchResultsTable);

               }

            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }

                finally
                {
                    if (conn != null)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }

                return SearchResultsTable ;
            }

        protected void  btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            EmployeeGridView.DataSource = Search();
            EmployeeGridView.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

How can I modify this so the search becomes more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wild card in your procedure to achieve your requirement

plz have a look at this

[stored procedure with wildcard parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601318/stored-procedure-with-wildcard-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL wildcard with LIKE operator.

```
and ( @Emp_name is null or Emp_name Like @Emp_name )+ '%'
```

would give you all matching results which start with 'P'. % will give substitute for all matching characters in database.

```
select * from yourTable where yourColumn= 'P%'
```

It is also advisable to send your search string uppercase/lowercase to your stored procedure. Then, you can uppercas/lowercase your database column in SQL query as well

```
select * from yourTable where UPPER(yourColumn)= 'P%'
```

> So searching for 'p%' or 'P%' would yield the same results